# Update not working with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update the `username` column on my database. My table has two columns: `username` and `phoneno`. The code which I have done is:

```php
<html>
    <body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $dbname = 'test';
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $new = $_POST['testing'];
    $sql = "UPDATE test SET username = $new WHERE phoneno = 2000,196,200" ;
    mysql_select_db('test');
    $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";

    mysql_close($conn);

    }
    else
    {

?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="testing">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I run this code it gives me this error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

I know it's due to the error in the query but I still didn't understand what the error means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using mysqli_* functions and selecting database via mysql_select_db. That is wrong. A connection string will look like.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

Missing quotes in your query condition.

```
$sql = "UPDATE test SET username = '$new' WHERE phoneno = '2000,196,200'";
```

mysqli_query needs connection string as the first parameter and query as the second one.

```
$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: @user3760836 happy to hear its working. Enjoy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

put quotes to your variable (string values) like this

```
UPDATE test SET username = '$new' WHERE phoneno IN( 2000,196,200)
```

put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of your page

Error reference link : http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Always print your query and check, also put `mysqli_error($conn);`

you have swap your variables in `mysqli_query` like this

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
```

Comment: see my answer in last line